# Can you GROUP_CONCAT IF results for a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I want to concat the results I find in a query.  The catch is I am aliasing the results based on the value of another column for that entry using an `IF` statement.

This works well

```
SELECT town
IF(is_found = 0, name, null) as not_found,
IF(is_found = 1, name, null) as found
FROM listing
```

But if I want to group my results by town I need to concat the results of the name listings.

I tried this:

```
SELECT town
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(is_found = 0, name, null) as not_found) as missing_list,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(is_found = 1, name, null) as found) as found_list
FROM listing
```

I am getting syntax errors.

How can I produce a concat'ed listing like this where the results are conditional on an IF statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as` doesn't go in the `if`.  So you can do:

```
SELECT town, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(is_found = 0, name, null)) as missing_list,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(is_found = 1, name, null)) as found_list
FROM listing
GROUP BY town;
```

I prefer `case` over `if` (because it is standard so available in virtually all databases):

```
SELECT town, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN is_found = 0 THEN name END) as missing_list,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN is_found = 1 THEN name END) as found_list
FROM listing
GROUP BY town;
```